# Bunch of private properties executed one by one

Tags: php, design-patterns

Is this a sign, that some design pattern is needed here?

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function filter($string)
{
    // underscored means private
    $this->_prepareSomething($string); 
    $this->_prepareSomething2();
    $this->_prepareSomething3();
    $this->_prepareSomething4();
    $this->_prepareSaveSomethingToFile();

    return $this->getFiltered();
}
```

Comment: Needs more information to really be able to tell.

Comment: Agree that we need more information, but it does look a bit like some abstraction may be applicable here.  It's hard to tell if it was just split up for testability (instead of having a monolithic routine, split it up to a bunch of smaller ones).  But it's still tightly coupled...  Perhaps a [Chain Of Responsibility](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) or a [Command](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) pattern may fit better.  But without knowing fully what it does, I'm not sure what's applicable here...

Comment: First thing that came to mind was a chain of responsibility as ircmaxell mentioned, however I think a little more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about readability and the right level of abstraction. For me as the reader it's hard to see what data is exchanged between the _prepare* functions. And, let's pretend they are calculations of some sort, then saving some data to file is mixing business logic with persistance. Which looks like mixing of abstraction levels.

Also, the getFiltered() call is also confusing, as it looks like a public method is called with a similar naming scheme as the original function.

Patterns: See http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/WikiPagesAboutRefactoring/ComposedMethod.html for the composed method pattern explanation, and http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/06/12/coding-single-level-of-abstraction-principle/ for the SLAP principle.

Comment: +1:  Plus, I'd HIGHLY recommend reading [Code Complete 2](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670), as it does a great job explaining all of this...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already implementing a [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  If your class will have subclasses which may need to override certain steps in that process, then I'd say you've already designed your base class effectively.